# Why is Dart/Flutter Stack Trace wrong in release mode (Android)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Calling `Trace.current()` in debug works perfectly. However, calling `Trace.current()` in release mode yields a different stack which is definitely wrong (this code path is impossible). *Most*, if not all stack traces I get in release mode are like this (where one or two function calls are wrong).

Debug stack trace, showing correct **GlobalChannelProxyService.createChannel** call:

```
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 52:36              RoomService._getCurrentFunctionName
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 134:25             RoomService.callServer
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/services/global_channel_proxy_service.dart 17:33  GlobalChannelProxyService.createChannel
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/main_page/chat/create_channel_dialog.dart 14:10   CreateChannelDialog.submit
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/main_page/chat/create_channel_dialog.dart 44:17   CreateChannelDialog.build.<fn>
...
```

Release stack trace, showing impossible **GameServiceProxy.executePlace** call:

```
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 52             RoomService._getCurrentFunctionName
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 134            RoomService.callServer
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/services/game_proxy_service.dart 84           GameServiceProxy.executePlace
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/main_page/chat/create_channel_dialog.dart 16  CreateChannelDialog.submit.<fn>
```

Please note *GameServiceProxy.executePlace* is never even called in the app. It is, however, an async function, which may be related. If I comment the *GameServiceProxy.executePlace* function, the release stack trace will be different, but still wrong:

Release stack trace with commented **GameServiceProxy.executePlace** function:

```
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 52              RoomService._getCurrentFunctionName
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 111             RoomService.reflectProp
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/services/self_user_proxy_service.dart 12       SelfUserProxyService.user
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 165             RoomService._callServerBase
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/room_service/room_service.dart 148             RoomService.callServer
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/services/global_channel_proxy_service.dart 17  GlobalChannelProxyService.createChannel
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/main_page/chat/create_channel_dialog.dart 14   CreateChannelDialog.submit
package:poly_scrabble_mobile/main_page/chat/create_channel_dialog.dart 33   CreateChannelDialog.build.<fn>
...
```

Please note the **SelfUserProxyService.user**, which is also an impossible path. It looks like 2 stack traces got mangled in this case.

Comment: You might want to file an issue against [`package:stack_trace`](https://github.com/dart-lang/stack_trace/issues) with more information, as it's possible this is a bug.

Comment: Added here for reference: https://github.com/dart-lang/stack_trace/issues/122